# Spring - Binding list with request param

Tags: spring, parameters, binding

I'm trying to map an array from url to a List but it doesn't work. I searched into stackoverflow but my case doesn't appear.
I do a call from a node js code that provide a specific URL to get some dishes with an array param.

There is my method which map with the url :

```
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Dish>> getDishes(
        ...
        @RequestParam(value = "status[]", required = false) List<DishStatus> status
        ...
        )
        throws Exception {
    //MY CODE
}
```

There is my url :

```
{my_url}/dishes?status%5B0%5D=ACTIVE&status%5B1%5D=INACTIVE
```

It seems that Spring doesn't recognize the `%5B0%5D` and `%5B1%5D` values in the URL. The link below without `%5B0%5D` and `%5B1%5D` works fine !

```
{my_url}/dishes?status=ACTIVE&status=INACTIVE
```

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i find a solution to fix my issue :

In my query, I set my query to : `{"status":"ACTIVE,INACTIVE"}` instead of `{"status":["ACTIVE","INACTIVE"]}`